# How to disable migrations for specific Django 1.7 apps?

Tags: python, django

How do you disable migrations for specific apps in Django>=1.7?

I'm trying to upgrade from Django 1.6 to 1.7, and I made some trivial changes to Django's auth app to change labels, but a design flaw in Django>=1.7 now treats all attributes as part of the database schema, triggering a new migration. Moreover, running `manage.py makemigration myapp` generates a migration for all other apps touching `myapp`, so even though I'm not explicitly trying to create a migration for `auth`, it's forcing me to do so, and I see no way to turn this off.

This is creating havoc, since I have a dozen apps that touch `auth`, so this is causing Django to create over a dozen pointless migrations.

I tried creating a custom `auth` migration directory using `MIGRATION_MODULES`, but doesn't seem to work. Any app that relies on auth now throws an error like:

```
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field helpdesk.Queue.group: auth.Group
```

If I try to migrate `auth`. How do I fix this? Ideally, the simplest solution would be to just "turn off" migrations for `auth`, since I'm not actually making any changes to it.

Edit: This is the custom migration Django forces me to generate:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('admin', '0001_initial'),
        ('auth', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='LogEntry',
            fields=[
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ('-action_time',),
                'verbose_name': 'log entry',
                'proxy': True,
                'verbose_name_plural': 'log entries',
            },
            bases=('admin.logentry',),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='permission',
            name='name',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='name'),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='username',
            field=models.CharField(help_text='Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', unique=True, max_length=75, verbose_name='username', validators=[django.core.validators.RegexValidator('^[\\w.@+-]+$', 'Enter a valid username.', 'invalid')]),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
    ]
```

My custom changes are to make the username and email fields the same length (because the two are the same in my system), as well as change the default validator to validate them both as an email address. I've been using these changes since Django 1.3. Presumably, they're only a problem now that I'm no longer using South and have to re-generate all my migrations.

And it looks like I can't use `MIGRATION_MODULES` to even generate this into a custom migration folder, because I have some other apps that depend on auth's 0001_initial migration, like:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]
```

So if I override it with `MIGRATION_MODULES` like:

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'auth': 'myoverrides.auth_migrations',
}
```

that migration effectively disappears, throwing the error.

Comment: You shouldn't be making changes to an app in Django itself. Can you give an example of the kind of changes you've made and the resulting migrations?

Comment: @Aniket You're suggesting I become a Django core dev and make all their apps unmanaged?!

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I've updated the details. I'm customizing the length of the username field and some other minor changes, none of which need to be migrated since the changes were applied to my database years ago.

Comment: "I'm customizing the length of the username field and some other minor changes" That's what [custom user models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) are for.

Comment: @Chris, Not really. I'm not *changing* the model. I *changed* the model...years ago. Rewriting hundreds of lines of code just to upgrade to Django 1.7's new migrations and a custom user model isn't something I want to do. All I want is for Django to **not** migrate the auto model, because it's no longer changing. Per that doc page, using a custom user model would require a huge refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack, but I modified my `settings.py` to check `sys.argv` for "makemigrations" and remove the conflicting apps, that are effectively unmanaged, from my `INSTALLED_APPS` list. This allowed me to properly generate a custom `auth` migration. e.g.

```
if 'makemigrations' in sys.argv
    INSTALLED_APPS.remove('conflicting_third_party_app')
```